# Как открыть некоторую часть web страницы в форме на c#

Tags: c#, webbrowser

Пишу небольшую программу (как тренировка в обучении): необходимо открыть web страницу. В теории это сделать довольно просто:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("http://google.com");
```

Но возможно ли как-то управлять той частью, которая отобразится в `webBrowser1`?
Допустим у меня `webBrowser1` размерами 200х200 и я хочу вывести правый верхний квадрат гугла. Это как-то возможно реализовать?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Нужно подписаться на событие `DocumentCompleted`, узнать ширину загруженного документа, ширину окна (заметьте, что она необязательно равна ширине самого контрола, т.к. например скроллбар может съедать место) и установить позицию скролла в нужное место:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;

...

private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(
    object sender,
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // получаем ширину документа, доступную для скролла
    var documentWidth = webBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width;
    // получаем реальную ширину окна документа
    var windowWidth = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Size.Width;
    // устанавливаем скролл в правый верхний угол
    webBrowser1.Document.Window.ScrollTo(documentWidth - windowWidth, 0);
}
```